# What is the correct implementation of a generic repository or unit of work and which should used with EF?

Tags: c#, generics, repository-pattern, entity-framework-6, unit-of-work

I have implemented a generic `Repository` and `UnitOfWork` found [here](http://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/).

My server-side stack is: C# .Net 4.5, EF6, AutoMapper (for EF model/DTO), Autofac (DI), WebAPI, OData.

My DI setup is as follows:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());                        // using extension to register all controllers in an assembly at once
builder.RegisterType<ProjectV001Context>().As<IDataContext>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
builder.RegisterType<Repository<ContentType>>().As<IRepository<ContentType>>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerHttpRequest();

builder.RegisterType<ContentTypesController>().As<IContentTypesController>().InstancePerHttpRequest();

var container = builder.Build();
```

Here is my OData controller:

```
public class ContentTypesController : ODataController, IContentTypesController
{

    // add repository reference
    private readonly IRepository<ContentType> _repository;

    private ProjectV001Context _db = new ProjectV001Context();

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor - setup for DI
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="contentTypeRepository"></param>
    public ContentTypesController(IRepository<ContentType> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    // GET odata/ContentTypes
    [Queryable]
    public virtual IEnumerable<ContentTypes> Get(ODataQueryOptions<ContentType> options)
    {
        // TODO:  Use try/catch or using / unitOfWOrk

        var userId = 102;   // mock
        var result = options.ApplyTo(_repository.Query().Get()
            .Where(u => u.UserId == userId)
            .OrderBy(o => o.Description)).Cast<ContentType>();

        var dto = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ContentType>,IEnumerable<ContentTypes>>(result); 

        return dto;
    }
}
```

Should I be using the UnitOfWork rather than the repository, and if so is the following a correct implementation?

```
using (var unitOfWork = new Repository.UnitOfWork(_db))
{
    var userId = 102;   // mock
    var result = options.ApplyTo(unitOfWork.Repository<ContentType>().Query().Get()
        .Where(u => u.UserId == userId)
        .OrderBy(o => o.Description)).Cast<ContentType>();

    var dto = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ContentType>, IEnumerable<ContentTypes>>(result);

    return dto;
}
```

Somehow I think this circumvents the whole DI thing - suggestions welcome.

**-- UPDATE --**

Here is the same code using the DF database context:

```
        using (var u = new ProjectV001Context())
        {
            var result = from contentTypes in u.ContentTypes
                         where contentTypes.UserId == userId
                         orderby contentTypes.Description
                         select contentTypes;
        }
```

There have been [other discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709971/should-i-be-using-a-generic-repository-with-entity-framework-5) [(and here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110890/not-using-repository-pattern-use-the-orm-as-is-ef/17473500#17473500) about whether or not to further abstract EF's db context, and as @qujck points out,

> ...having your own abstraction for UnitOfWork and Repository gives you
>   maximum control and flexibility when mocking your unit tests.
>
> All very well, but for me, the real power of these abstractions is
>   they provide a simple way to apply Aspect Oriented Programming
>   techniques and adhere to the SOLID principles.

I have reworded the question to include the initial intent:  In the first sample, I am using a generic repository, creating a specific repository for each type, in this case, `ContentTypes`.

So just accepting that I am using the generic framework... Looking at the bootstrap setup:

```
        builder.RegisterType<Repository<ContentType>>().As<IRepository<ContentType>>().InstancePerHttpRequest();

    builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerHttpRequest();

    builder.RegisterType<ContentTypesController>().As<IContentTypesController>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

If I used the generic repository, I would have to register a separate repository for each type, rather than just one registration for the `UnitOfWork` (seems more efficient).

My idea for an initial setup for using the `UnitOfWork` is as follows:

```
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;

    public ContentTypesController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _uow = unitOfWork;
    }
```

Implementation:

```
        try
        {
            var result = options.ApplyTo(_uow.Repository<ContentType>().Query().Get()
                .Where(u => u.UserId == userId)
                .OrderBy(o => o.Description)).Cast<ContentType>();

            IQueryable<ContentTypes> dto = result.Project().To<ContentTypes>();

            return dto;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

In this case, I'm not using a `using()` statement, as when I do I get an error 500.  What I'm finding is that the `Dispose` method is being called twice:

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

Is this implementation correct (should I be using the `Repository` rather than `uow`), and is it best to use the `UnitOfWork` or `Repository` implementation, and how do ensure I'm using my DI framework with this `UnitOfWork` implementation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21584605/304832

Comment: Your controller should get the uow via the constructor. What is your problem with this?

Comment: @WiktorZychla - I forgot to add the implementation - it's there now.

Comment: Personally I would argue against adding layer upon layer upon layer like this. Unnecessary complication is one of the great evils of coding, easy to talk yourself into it but makes for a real pain to get actual work done. EF is all about making it easier and your code cleaner, while still giving you as much flexibility as possible.

Comment: @ElHaix: this looks ok. If your unit of work is injected, then you **don't have to dispose it in the constructor** as the disposal will be done outside, at the end of the request pipeline.

Comment: @TimothyWalters And I would argu that data centric apps can greatly benefit from a unified business layer and logic. A proper implemented Repository and UnitOfWork pattern should not add complexity to anything beside creating a new table, which is a 5 min task to begin with. But forgetting a data operation on creation or update of an entity because of the lack of a business layer can be very costy in both troubleshooting and data corruption if pushed on live environment. In any application that has a different main focus, then yes, I would agree that EF itself is a good enough DAL+Domain combo